Is it possible to derive $E$ field and $B$ field of a system that is fairly non-symmetric at every point in space?
While learning electro and magneto statics for the first time we derived formulae for very specific systems like infinite wire, cylinder, infinite sheet, ring, disc etc. These usually required heavy integration (or use of gauss law mostly in cases of infinite objects). Are there methods to determine these for any arbitrary shape at any point in space say a triangular lamina?

Of course. You simply take the formalism you learned in class and replace the charge distribution with whatever shape you want. The required integrals will get really messy, though.

Theoretical physics is mostly an exploration of the structure of our physical theories. Beyond that there are usually only a handful of systems that can be solved explicitly and they all tend to have rather high symmetry. Apart from giving formal implicit solutions we can at best go at general systems numerically. For static charge distributions there are fairly simple integrals that allow us to deduce their fields directly. The hard problems are those where neither the fields nor the charge distributions are known initially.
